# Laplace transform of Dirac delta

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

I need some assistance with a question involving the Dirac delta

$$y''(t)=t^3δ(t-2), y(0)=y'(0)=0$$

I'm assuming the first step is

$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)=L((t^3)δ(t-2))$$

but I'm having trouble finding the Laplace of the RHS

any advice would be appreciated thanks

Comment: What's the definition of the Laplace transform? What do Dirac delta functions do to integrals?

Comment: The RHS after your first step is no correct. You should write $L\left(t^{3}\delta(t-2)\right)$ and follow the @SeanLake's hints.

Comment: I forgot about the brackets but thats what i was meant to type, its fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrals with Dirac functions are so easy that they're hard.  $\delta(t-2)=0$ everywhere except when $t=2$, and then it has weight 1.  So $\int_0^{\infty} \delta(t-2)f(t) \; dt = f(2).$